# failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections while upload on amazon EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

i am using the amazon EC2 server for hosting..

I have faced one problem :-i have to copy one file from my server to amazon bucket

for that i am using

$str = file_get_contents('http://www.custmore.com/dev/usercontent/userphoto/user_photo_1358927451.jpg');

file_put_contents"(http://s3.amazonaws.com/custmorebuck/test", $str);

But getting error

failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Can anyone suggest to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to use stream wrappers.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=283440

hope the above link helps.